# Select the data from the updated database

Tags: php, mysql

In my database i have column vv that had values in ""09.12.2019 12:55:50"". So i dont want remove my records and updated my data to this format 2019-12-09 12:55:50 but i am not getting any result against $result2. I am even not getting any error. The input values i am selecting has data against it in database but i am getting the output in $result2.

```
<?php
 include("includes\conn.php"); 
 $start = $_POST['start_date'];
 $temp_date= substr($start, 0, 10);
 $temp_date1= substr($start, 11, 17);
 $final= $temp_date.' '.$temp_date1;
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"$result = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `data` SET `vv` = STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(`vv`, '.', '-'), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')");");
 $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM data WHERE vv = '$final'");
 print_r($result2);
?>
```

Your Kind help is needed!

Comment: you don't need the first query, just do `STR_TO_DATE(vv, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')` if your `vv` data is in format `09.12.2019 12:55:50`. and btw, do you have double quotes as well as part of `vv` strings?

Comment: Does it make sense to name a table `vv`?

Comment: @B001ᛦ, `vv` is the column, the table itself is named `data` :)

Comment: @mitkosoft sure! I meant actually the column :)

Comment: Still wondering about these double-quotes, are they part of the date string?

Comment: What is the result you get? `print_r` should show you something.

Comment: @mitkosoft yes double-quotes are the part of the string and i need data in the format of Y-m-d  STR_TO_DATE(vv, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') does that.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It shows mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 4 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you produce in `$final` variable, but assuming you have there a string that represent some proper datetime like `2019-12-09 12:55:50`, then you need to execute the following `UPDATE` query that will convert `""09.12.2019 12:55:50""` to `2019-12-09 12:55:50` strings:

```
UPDATE `data` SET `vv` = STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(`vv`, '"', ''), '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

However, executing an `UPDATE` on every `POST` request in order to get a `SELECT` result afterwards is simply very bad approach. Better consider to  `ALTER` your table and convert this nasty `vv` column into real `datetime` datatype format once you convert all the strings there.

Comment: It still gives no output

Comment: You know probably that `print_r($result2)` will not give you the result actually, but you have to fetch the row(s)? what is the value of `num_rows` now there?

Comment: it gives zero still

Comment: Well, you have to debug two things - how the values in `vv` column looks like now (share it here) and what do you have as an exact string in your `$final` variable (share it also).

Comment: i know this is not a good approach but this table is always loading with data and it is in the string format and i just to fetch it. That is why i am using this approach

Comment: And as I mentioned, your first `UPDATE` is not needed, so remove it from the code (`$result` row).

Comment: my vv column has 2019-12-09 12:55:50 in it and $final after the update query has 2019-12-09 12:55:50 but it is still not fetching any row. i have updated my code according to your suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206923/discussion-between-mitkosoft-and-maria-abdullah).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206929/discussion-between-mitkosoft-and-maria-abdullah).